# List of built-in .NET Framework types that are value types according to Type.IsValueType

Tags: .net, types, value-type

I'd like a list of all the built-in .NET Framework types for which `Type.IsValueType` would return true. Is there a way I can generate that list (i.e. is there a way I can get a list of all the built-in types from within .NET itself)?

I'm writing some code where I'm trying to determine if I've been passed some sort of POCO or anonymous type for which I'll look at the object's properties, or whether I've been given a value (or value-like) type and I'll just directly use its value. I know already that I'm going to need check whether the object is type `String` since I'll want to use its value rather than look at its properties. I'm wanting to make sure there aren't any other exceptions I need to worry about.

Comment: A value type doesn't necessarily have only one value. It can have any number of fields. What are you trying to do in the end?

Comment: Good call. I'm taking a `ParamArray` (pardon the VB-speak) of `Object` and using that as a source for SQL parameters . If you give me a (String, Integer, Boolean) then I'll use those as parameters (@0, @1, @2), but if you give me a POCO or anonymous type, I'm going to try to match @UserId to a property called UserId.

Comment: Hmmm... so you're limited by what SQL allows (what you will find in the System.Data.SqlTypes namespace) anyway. I think it's easier to hardcode the well-known types, and process the rest, whether it's a value or reference type (values types may also have properties).

Comment: Why not just trust the documentation for a list of value types.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: Yea, "value types with properties" is what I was wanting to avoid. Rather than hard-coding all the types, I was hoping that I could create a concise statement like `type.IsValueType OrElse type Is GetType(String)`... I think that would be sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it really makes sense but you could enumerate the value types from all the assemblies which are relevant to your use case with something like

```
  // do this for all assemblies you care about
  Assembly assembly = ... // e.g. Assembly.LoadFrom(info.FullName);
  foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
  {
    if(type.IsValueType)
    {
      ... // whatever
    }                    
  }
```

It really depends on what you consider "built-in .NET Framework types". E.g. are types from WPF or ASP.NET MVC built in or not? However, your use case seems quite strange to me, I am not sure I understood what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Maybe you could use only base type? I.e. things from WPF ultimately inherit from `Object`, you can just consider all those "type" of things to just be an `Object`. Or would that result in unexpected results?

Comment: I am not sure I got it - everything ultimately inherits from Object (including `System.ValueType`), so I don't see how it would help.

Comment: yes, `typeof(System.Int32).BaseType == typeof(System.ValueType)`